# Password reset using password.js in sails.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, sails.js, passport.js

I am developing my first [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) app. I have used [sails-generate-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-generate-auth) as my authentication generator. I want to implement forgot password for an existing user in my system. I have generated my temporary password the same way as passport does. How do I reset the password of this user to my auto generated password? I'm confused.

Comment: Hello Jassem. What did you do to solve this?

Comment: @Jaseem Abbas Have you already solved it? I would like to see your GitHub repo if so.